# Getting Exception in Angular2 EXCEPTION: No provider for PlatformLocation?

Tags: angular

Getting below on exception in browser console.

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for PlatformLocation!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/core.umd.js:3776:27)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4307:20)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/core.umd.js:4342:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5794:23)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5822:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5785:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/core.umd.js:5594:25)
    at _View_WalletPlus_Host0.createInternal (WalletPlus_Host.template.js:38:83)
    at _View_WalletPlus_Host0.AppView.create (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/core.umd.js:9862:25)
    at _View_WalletPlus_Host0.DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:3000/lib/@angular/core/core.umd.js:10054:48)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

Please help to resolve this. Not understanding what is the issue exactly.

below is index.ts where i am bootstrapping my application.

```
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {enableProdMode,provide} from "@angular/core";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/router";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";
import {MyAppComponent} from "./components/MyApp.component";
import {SimpleExpiry} from 'ng2-idle/simpleexpiry';

import {APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(<any>MyAppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS,SimpleExpiry,
provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: "/" }),
provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be  missing **`NativeScriptRouterModule`** inside imports the in main.ts file.

```
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        routableComponents,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    ],
})
```

Comment: I am using angular 2.0.0-rc.1 version (release candidate) not stable version.